# how to get windows phone 8 app version from windows app store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

I want to find my windows phone app version from market place.
 Is it possible to find current app version from market? if ,then help me to  find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Windows Phone 8.1**

If you swipe to the "details" panel on the app's page, it should say the app version at the top under "Information". It includes the current version as well as the last time the app was updated.

**For Windows Phone 8**

On the main panel for the app, underneath the information, there should be a "Report concern to Microsoft" link. Just beneath this link is information on the Publisher, last update and the current version.

Let me know if this helps!